# Can't run OpenGL on Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell

When I am trying to run this code, taken from:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop

display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
  clear [ ColorBuffer ]
  flush
```

I got an error in WinGHCi:

```
*** Exception: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)
```

I have updated the Haskell Platform just today, and it is said that OpenGL is a part of libraries now. So what is the problem? I feel like I have forgotten about something really obvious.

Comment: The tutorial you linked suggests: "Alas, on some platforms GHCi has problems running the following programs, so you might have to compile them with GHC and run the generated executables instead." (FWIW, it works here under Linux.)

Comment: I have compiled it, but the error remains. By the way it would be really suprising if I really have to compile it all the time.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the glut library. Do you have it on your path somewhere? The OpenGL bindings come with the Haskell Platform but from what I remember, the library does not. If you don't have it, you should use freeglut over over glut.

Comment: Or switch to GLFW right away. It's quite similar to GLUT (not "more functional" unfortunately), but a bit less clunky. — Speaking of switching... yeah, pretty much everything in Haskell is easier to set up on a UNIX-like system, and on GNU/Linux distributions in particular. Just sayin'...

Comment: I have checked using command ghc-pkg list , and GLUT OpenGl and Raw things are in my haskell platform. I am not sure what do you mean by Path. Also I don't know how can I setup GLFW. I have read readme.

Comment: The things in your Haskell platform are merely the _Haskell bindings_, but all these graphics libraries are actually programmed in C and need to be installed separately, which I suppose is, on Windows, not quite so easy. In e.g. Ubuntu it's just a matter of `sudo apt-get install libglfw-dev` (for the C library), and then `cabal install GLFW` for the Haskell bindings.