# How do I solve "(unknown GLUT entry glutInit)" while trying to run a Gloss program?

Tags: macos, haskell

I am new to haskell but I'm trying to run a program with the Gloss library. I have installed it the library and all its dependencies with no problems, can compile a file with the Gloss library imported, but when I try to actually run a test program like this one (my typing "main" in ghci after the file is loaded):

```
-- | Display "Hello World" in a window.
--
import Graphics.Gloss

main    
 = display 
        (InWindow
           "Hello World"     -- window title
        (400, 150)   -- window size
        (10, 10))    -- window position
    white            -- background color
    picture          -- picture to display

picture 
    = Translate (-170) (-20) -- shift the text to the middle of the window
    $ Scale 0.5 0.5      -- display it half the original size
    $ Text "Hello World"     -- text to display
```

I end up getting the following text in ghci (version 8.0.1):

```
*** Exception: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)
```

I have googled this problem but all solutions seems to be [if you are on windows you should add some dll file glut32.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038674/cant-run-opengl-on-haskell). But I'm on OS X Mavericks so what do I do to make it work? Can anyone help with getting Gloss programs to run on OS X? I don't even understand what "unknown GLUT entry glutInit" means. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried the workarounds here: https://github.com/haskell-opengl/GLUT/issues/19